# Python aggregate based on multiple columns

Tags: python

I've got 2 tables of User ID's and emails.
A user can change their email but keep the same user ID (row 2 and row 5 of USER_PLAYS table).
A user can also create a new user ID with an existing email (row 3 of USER_PLAYS table).
I want to be able to sum up the total plays for this user into a single row.
There is also another table with sales value that I would like to get the total sales.
I'm thinking somehow to create a unique ID that is the same across all these fields but not sure how to implement it.

Note that I've only shown 1 actual person but there are multiple more unique people in these tables.

LOGIC:
We know that row 1 and 2 are the same user because they have the same USER_ID and we know that row 2,3,4 are all the same User because they have the same email. We know that row 4 and 5 are the same user because they have the same USER_ID. Therefore we can conclude that all rows are the same user.

```
USER_PLAYS table:

|ROW|USER_ID    | EMAIL              |VIDEO_PLAYS|
|---|-----------|--------------------|-----------|
|1  | 1         |  ab@gmail.com      |    2      |
|2  | 1         |  cd@gmail.com      |    3      |
|3  | 3         |  cd@gmail.com      |    4      |
|4  | 4         |  cd@gmail.com      |    2      |
|5  | 4         |  ef@gmail.com      |    3      |

Sales Table:
|NET_SALE   | EMAIL       |
|-----------|-------------|
|5          | cd@gmail.com|
|10         | ef@gmail.com|

Desired Output:
|UNIQUE_ID  | PLAYS |NET_SALE|
|-----------|-------|--------|
| 1         |  14   |  15    |
```

Comment: Are you using `pandas` for your tables ? It is not very clear how your tables are implemented

Comment: What is a _table_?

Comment: Yes you can view each table as a pandas dataframe instead.